# TrueCrypt - mounting an "FDE" encrypted multi-volume disk in one operation?

Tags: windows-7, encryption, mount, truecrypt, veracrypt

tl;dr -- **How do you mount a secondary hard disk with multiple volumes that was encrypted with "full disk encryption" by TrueCrypt?**

---

My **secondary** 1TB hard disk has 4 volumes on it, an old Windows 7 standard desktop installation.  When it was new I encrypted it entirely (all 1TB in one "fully encrypt system drive" operation using **TrueCrypt 7.1**).  So when I used to have it as my main bootable system disk I would get the TrueCrypt password prompt immediately at bootup and that would enable the system to access the Windows installation.

Now I'm booting off an SSD drive with a fresh Windows 7 installation on it.

I have hit a problem I didn't foresee when I upgraded to the new SSD.  It would seem that I cannot persuade VeraCrypt or Truecrypt to mount the old drive.

The new system can see the 4 volumes on the encrypted disk, but I cannot work out how to mount any of them.

While the old drive is theoretically bootable, I do not want to mount that disk in anything other than read-only mode if possible.

Further info:

- There are no hidden volumes on the encrypted disk.
- The encrypted disk is in good health and has no corruption, it was booted successfully recently and shutdown cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  It is possible to use linux tools `tcplay` and `kpartx` to decrypt and mount all partitions on a "Full Disk Encryption" affected hard disk.

This can be done by booting from an Ubuntu USB stick.

Quite a painless process actually, the `man` pages for both tools are enough information to get this done.

As usual it's Linux to the rescue :)